# Data result from Axios

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, axios

I'm new to Axio and React, I would like to know how to return my results from Axio.
My console.log shows all my arrays send by PHP perfectly but it won't return in my HTML code.

Here is my code

```
axios.get('api.php').then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
    return result.data
});
```

I tried using innerHTML but it's giving me

```
[object Object]
```

And adding `.macdb` after `result.data` gives me an `undefined`

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are trying to display the returned data in some meaningful way. In react this is accomplished by rendering some JSX from state and/or props. With async data fetches you'll want to update your state after the response is received instead of returning it (wrapped in a promise).

```
axios.get('api.php')
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
    this.setState({ data: result.data });
  });
```

A typical pattern for fetching data is to do it in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function (in the case of class-based components) or an `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array (for functional components).

```
class Demo extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('api.php')
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
        this.setState({ data: result.data });
      });
  }
}
```

or

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api.php')
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
        setData(result.data);
      });
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: I tried these 3 options but none are working... What can I do ?

Comment: @spock If you update your question to include the entire component code *and* a copy of an example result response we can better inform how to handle it. Your internal state and API response can be literally anything, I just took a guess they are plain objects.